# Why using "root" is better than using "alias" in nginx configuration?

Tags: nginx

All the posts I went through agree that using `root` and `alias` directives can sometimes lead to similar results, as in the following example:

- Using the `alias` directive:

  ```
  location /images/ {
      alias /data/w3/images/;
  }
  ```
- Using the `root` directive:

  ```
  location /images/ {
      root /data/w3;
  }
  ```

All things being equal, I would personally prefer using `alias` to have the `$document_root` pointing to the actual document root instead of its parent directory and limit nasty issues would I mistakenly forget the trailing `/` in the `location` value.

However, [nginx documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias) explicitly states that in such circumstances:

> it is better to use the root directive instead

Why is it so? While I see arguments in favor to `alias`, I do not see why `root` is the preferred one?

Comment: You forgot the rest of the sentence: "When location matches the last part of the directive’s value" then "it is better to use the root directive instead". Use alias only when it's unavoidable.

Comment: @MichaelHampton: Thanks for the precision, I thought the rest of my post made it already clear. You seem to talk like the us of `alias` was some kind of bad nasty workaround? Does it cause sensible performance issue, stability or security concerns, or anything else? All references I've found just tell that apart from the `$document_root` content difference they produce an identical behavior with comparable performance so I do not understand why `alias` should be used only *"when it's unavoidable"*... What is the consequence if I use it instead of `root`?

Comment: `root` is a little faster. Nginx just need to concatenate two strings and don't need to cut off matching part from URI

Comment: @RichardSmith: Thanks, this is precisely the kind of information I was looking for :) !

Comment: @AlexeyTen: While in theory this may be true, I wonder if this makes any practical difference. I did not found any article mentioning `alias` acting as a bottleneck and the need to replace it by `root` directives to solve a performance issue. It is not mentioned in the [pitfalls list](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/), does not cause any complete reparsing of the configuration or subrequest handling, and usually performance related articles focus more on things like IO and buffers handling.

Comment: The above mentioned link seems to have moved here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20426812/nginx-try-files-alias-directives
Or is this yet another thing?